# Swapping two components in extjs

Tags: extjs, swap

I have two components in my form which are "Source" and "Destination". And I want to give an  option to change the order of those 2 components when clicked on "Swap" button.
Is this achievable in Extjs form ..?
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ej6

Comment: Do you want to swap the values in the comboboxes, or you want to swap the comboboxes' order itself?

Comment: @AndreaRighi,
Not the values Righi, combo boxes order itself. It is similar to google source and destination swap. like we can change order source-destination or destination-source

Comment: did you check if the new solution?

Comment: Hi @AndreaRighi,
Yes this is working as expected, but I don't know its a good idea to depend on index.
it works if form is having less number of components, But what if I had form with lot of data

Answer (score 0):

I attach here one possible solution: I removed both the fields and added them again with right indices.

```
listeners: {
  click: function(){
    const panel = this.up('panel');

    const sourceForm = panel.query('combo[reference=source]');
    const destinationForm = panel.query('combo[reference=destination]');

    panel.remove(sourceForm)
    panel.remove(destinationForm)

    panel.insert(0, destinationForm)
    panel.insert(1, sourceForm)
  }
}
```

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3eja) the link to working Fiddle.

---- EDIT -----

This is the new snippet to adapt the fiddle to your comment:

```
const panel = this.up('panel');

const sourceForm = panel.query('combo[reference=source]');
const destinationForm = panel.query('combo[reference=destination]');

const sourceIndex = panel.items.items.indexOf(sourceForm[0])

panel.remove(sourceForm)
panel.remove(destinationForm)

panel.insert(sourceIndex, destinationForm)
panel.insert(sourceIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0, sourceForm)
```

The working fiddle can be found at the same old [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3eja/).

Comment: This behavior, I was doing in other way too, but the thing is how I should get the vice versa of swap.
1.Initially, it will be source-destination
2.Swap clicked, now positions changed to destination-source
3.Again clicked on swap, then it should come back to source-destination

There will be no control on swap button, user can click n number of times

Comment: I added a new snippet to fulfill your new requirements

Answer (score 0):

Different approach can be found here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3em7

```
  let combo1 = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'source',
            fieldLabel: 'source',
            reference: 'source',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            store: [{
                abbr: 'AL',
                name: 'Alabama'
            }, {
                abbr: 'AK',
                name: 'Alaska'
            }, {
                abbr: 'AZ',
                name: 'Arizona'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',

            }],
            allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
        })

        let combo2 = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'source1',
            fieldLabel: 'dest',
            reference: 'source1',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            //hidden: true,
            store: [{
                abbr: 'AL',
                name: 'Alabama'
            }, {
                abbr: 'AK',
                name: 'Alaska'
            }, {
                abbr: 'AZ',
                name: 'Arizona'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',

            }],
            allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
        })

        let items = [combo1, combo2];

        let wrapper = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: items
        })

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Contact Info',
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [wrapper, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: "Swap",
               handler:(b)=> {
                   wrapper.removeAll(false);
                   wrapper.add(items.reverse());
               }
            }]
        });
```

---

Technically, as far as i remember, items within a (container) component are managed using a mixed collection.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.util.MixedCollection.html

You can try to change the order there and refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we missed the CSS only solution.

You can use `ordinal-group` to swap items. Just add a class, which adds a higher group number to the first combobox.

```
listeners: {
    click: function () {
        let view = this.up(),
            sourceComp = view.down('combo[reference=source]');

        sourceComp.toggleCls('box-reverse')
    }
}

.box-reverse {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3!important;
}
```

Here is your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3en4)